# How to build typescript and scss together in a single file using rollup

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, rollup, turborepo

So, I'm trying to build a design system using turborepo, react, typescript and scss.

For reference I'm using https://github.com/vercel/turbo/tree/main/examples/design-system

The folder structure  is like:

```
my-app/
├─ apps/
│  ├─ docs/
├─ packages/
│  ├─ button/
│  │  ├─ src/
│  │  │  ├─ style.scss
│  │  │  ├─ Button.tsx
│  │  │  ├─ index.ts
│  │  ├─ package.json
│  │  ├─ rollup.config.json
```

I'm trying to build the package through rollup, but the scss file is not being used in build file.

**rollup.config.js**

```
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import sass from "rollup-plugin-sass";

const packageJson = require("./package.json");

export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      file: packageJson.main,
      format: "cjs",
      sourcemap: true,
    },
    {
      file: packageJson.module,
      format: "esm",
      sourcemap: true,
    },
  ],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({ useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true }),
    sass({ insert: true }),
  ],
};
```

I tried different rollup packages but none of them are working.

---

Some of the other configs that I have tried.

```
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import scss from "rollup-plugin-scss";

const packageJson = require("./package.json");

export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: {
    file: packageJson.module,
    format: "esm",
    assetFileNames: "[name][extname]",
  },
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    resolve(),
    commonjs(),
    typescript({ useTsconfigDeclarationDir: true }),
    scss(),
  ],
};
```